# iOS: EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN in generated CoreData code

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data, automatic-ref-counting

I feel like I'm starting to lose my sanity over this issue.

I've begun work on a CoreData iOS app, using the generated CoreData code that the SDK provides. My issue arises whenever I attempt to instantiate a new instance of an entity so that I can save it.

Here's the instantiation code I have, per the Apple CoreData tutorial, inside my AppDelegate (I've moved a bunch of my code there just to try to debug this issue):

```
NSManagedObjectContext* context = [self managedObjectContext];
if (!context)
{
    NSLog(@"Error"); // I'm not too concerned about my error handling just yet
}
```

Right after that, here's the line that produces the error I'm experiencing:

```
Vehicle* vehicle = (Vehicle*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Vehicle" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

The error in question is:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN address=0xdeadbeef)
```

All in all, I don't really know what that means other than there's a memory alignment issue (common with ARMv7?) and the resources I've found on Google haven't helped me in the slightest.

The only other relevant piece of code is the 'managedObjectContext' method provided by Xcode when it generates the project, because that's what generated the managedObjectContext in the first place:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (__managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return __managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }

    return __managedObjectContext;
}
```

Like I said, I'm way out of my depth here. Can anyone offer a bit of clarity as to how I could possibly resolve this?

Comment: Is your data model in `xcdatamodeld` defined correctly?

Comment: Based on all documentation I've found on CoreData, along with the corresponding tutorials provided by Apple, yes.

Comment: Try 1) Product - Clean. 2) Restart Xcode.

Comment: It is not about alignment, it is about uninitialized/deallocated memory `0xdeadbeef`. How did you initialize `__managedObjectContext`?

Comment: try setting _managedObjectContext to nil in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Answer (score 4):

It is likely that `__managedObjectContext` was not initialized (hence has value of `0xdeadbeef`) which cause `EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN` as side effect when try to read value from it.

@Kenny Winker
`EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN` is normally come from access pointer value that is not actual type. e.g.

```
char buf[8];
double d = *((double *)buf); // this may cause EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN
```

but it may also be caused invalid valid in pointer, which in this case, `0xdeadbeef`. e.g.

```
double *ptr; // not initialized
double d = *ptr; // this is undefined behaviour, which may cause EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN or other error
```

It is generally hard to debug these kind of bugs, here are some tips:

1. Check all pointer cast (i.e. `(double *)(void *)ptr`) and try to avoid them when possible.
2. Make sure everything is initialized.
3. When it crashed, find out which variable cause it crash and try to trace back to find out where is the value come from. Use debugger to watch a memory location can be helpful to find out all changes to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I thought it might be helpful to show a core data stack that is in operation. I will also show a part of the object diagram..

```
pragma mark -
#pragma mark Core Data stack

/**
 Returns the managed object context for the application.
 If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
 */


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    //  NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    if (managedObjectContext_ != nil) {

        return managedObjectContext_;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];

    if (coordinator != nil) {

        managedObjectContext_ = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];

        [managedObjectContext_ setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

    }

    return managedObjectContext_;
}

/**
 Returns the managed object model for the application.
 If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from a starter file.
 */


- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    //NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    if (managedObjectModel_ != nil) {
        return managedObjectModel_;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"DreamCatching" withExtension:@"mom"];
    managedObjectModel_ = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];    
    return managedObjectModel_;
}

/**
 Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
 If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
 */
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    //NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    if (persistentStoreCoordinator_ != nil) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
    }



    NSString *storePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DreamCatching.sqlite"];


    // If the expected store doesn't exist, copy the default store.

    //COMMENT / UNCOMMENT THIS TO LOAD / NOT LOAD THE STARTER FILE.
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storePath]) {        
        NSError *error;
        NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Starter" ofType:@"sqlite"];

        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:storePath error:&error]) 
            NSLog(@"Copied starting data to %@", storePath);
        else 
            NSLog(@"Error copying default DB to %@ (%@)", storePath, error);
    }
    // to below here




    NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath];


    NSError *error = nil;
    persistentStoreCoordinator_ = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator_ addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                     configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Error - App Delegate Creating DB %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application's Documents directory

/**
 Returns the path to the application's Documents directory.
 NB SETTINGS ARE NOT IN THIS DIRECTORY, THEY ARE IN THE APPS BUNDLE. CONTROL-CLICK THE APP TO SEE CONTENTS, CONTROL-CLICK THE BUNDLE TO SEE THE PREFS
 */
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    //NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}
```

and the model:

[image]